# JSQmessageviewcontroller: Bubbles without tails

Tags: ios, objective-c, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am using the JSQmessageviewcontroller, but i want the bubbles to have no tail, just to be rounded rectangles, is this possible? I currently do something like:

```
JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory *bubbleFactory = [[JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory alloc] init];
self.outgoingMessageBubble = [bubbleFactory incomingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.949 green:0.949 blue:0.949 alpha:1]];
```

I would like it to look something like:

[image]

Also is there a way to adjust the distances between the two bubble?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ya what you want to do is make pass the tailless image into your JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory for

Objective C:

```
JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory *bubbleFactoryOutline = [[JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory alloc] initWithBubbleImage:[UIImage jsq_bubbleRegularStrokedImage] capInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
```

Swift:

```
JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory(bubbleImage: UIImage.jsq_bubbleCompactTaillessImage(), capInsets: UIEdgeInsetsZero).
```

As for making the distance between messages you just need to changed the height of the upper label 
objective C:

```
(CGFloat)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView
               layout:(JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout *)collectionViewLayout heightForMessageBubbleTopLabelAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 0.0f;
}
```

Swift:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, layout collectionViewLayout: JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout!, heightForMessageBubbleTopLabelAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
    return 20
}
```

Swift 3:

```
JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory(bubble: UIImage.jsq_bubbleCompactTailless(), capInsets: .zero)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 3.0

```
JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory(bubble: UIImage.jsq_bubbleCompactTailless(), capInsets: .zero)
```

Comment: I'm using this exactly version: Version 8.1 (8B62). Are you using cocoaPods?

Comment: very Thanks that you replied, but code is working now,   and Yes, I'm using cocoaPods . this blog helped me- https://www.syncano.io/blog/create-ios-chat-app-part1/